# Adding justified text to image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I already can add text to an image using Pillow in Python. However, I want to know how I can add formatted text. In particular, I want to add a box of text to an image such that the text is center justified.

If this isn't possible using Pillow, I am open to other image manipulation libraries (including in other languages) that make overlaying formatted text on images easier.

Answer (score 2):

refer to the function in this link - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text

the first argument is location. you can give it based on the size of your image on which you want to add text.

Comment: wouldn't this just give me left aligned text that starts at the x value I provide?

Comment: As the first argument is a tuple of x and y values, you can give them as half of the size of the image you want the text to be on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple library which does the job of text alignment using PIL:
https://gist.github.com/turicas/1455973

Comment: An updated version from the gist comment https://gist.github.com/pojda/8bf989a0556845aaf4662cd34f21d269